# parsing json gives undefined property error

Tags: php, json

am trying to parse json values with the help of php. everything works fine but the subsequent arrays are not getting printed instead i am getting undefined property error. My first array gets displayed very easily. am following

http://www.bewebdeveloper.com

but have modified as per my requirement

please point where am making the mistake

here is my json file

```
    {
"result": {
"n":"2",
"title": "Rendering Json",
"10": "First Heading",
"1": [
    {
"1": "How to Create an RSS Feed with PHP and MySQL",
"11": "XRT"
}
],
"20": "Second Heading",
"2": [
    {
"2": "How to Create an RSS Feed with PHP and MySQL",
"21": "XRT",
"link": "http://www.bewebdeveloper.com/tutorial-about-how-to-create-an-rss-feed-with-php-and-mysql"
}
]
}
}
```

Here are my php codes

```
    <?php
// copy file content into a string var
$json_file = file_get_contents('jso.txt');
// convert the string to a json object
$jfo = json_decode($json_file);
// read the title value
$title = $jfo->result->title;
// copy the posts array to a php var
$r=1;
$posts = $jfo->result->$r;

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>How to parse JSON file with PHP</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="header">
<img src="images/BeWebDeveloper.png" />
</div><!-- header -->
<h1 class="main_title"><?php echo $title; ?></h1>
<div class="content">
<table>
 <?php
 $rt=$jfo->result->n;

  for($i=0; $i < $rt; $i++) {
 $x=1;
 ?>
 <th>
 <?php
 $ze=0;
 $p=$r.$ze;
 echo $jfo->result->$p;

 ?>
 </th>
<?php

foreach ($posts as $post) {
 $a=$i+1;
?>
<tr>
<td>

<h2><?php echo $post->$a; ?></h2>
</td>
 <td>
<h2><?php

$z=$a.$x; echo $post->$z; ?></h2>
 </td>
<td>
<?php
echo $a.$x;
$x++;
?>
</td>
</tr>
<?php
} // end foreach

$r++;

}

?>
</table>
 </div><!-- content -->
 <div class="footer">
 Powered by <a href="http://www.bewebdeveloper.com">bewebdeveloper.com</a>
 </div><!-- footer -->
 </div><!-- container -->
 </body>
 </html>
```

this is how my output looks like

Rendering Json

First Heading

How to Create an RSS Feed with PHP and MySQL  XRT   11

Second Heading

Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$2 in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-12.1\www\bobaloffers\json\json.php on line 50

Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$21 in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-12.1\www\bobaloffers\json\json.php on line 55   21

Powered by bewebdeveloper.com

please point what prevents the subsequent errors from getting parsed

Comment: So where are lines 50 and 55 in all of that?

Comment: line 50 : <?php echo $post->$a; ?>

Comment: line 55 : $z=$a.$x; echo $post->$z;

Comment: i have already mentioned am a json beginner and following http://www.bewebdeveloper.com it would be better if you could guide me instead of marking my question as a negative one

Comment: @developerwjk : if you cant answer then don't answer no need to mark my question as a negative one. if you are genius then its of no use if you cant guide. just watch this space i will answer my own question

Comment: There's no such thing as "marking a question as a negative one." There is however downvoting a question because the questioner didn't spend enough time to make the code remotely readable.  Fix the indenting. Beginner or not, you ought to know that stuff inside `{` and `}` needs to be tabbed over to make it readable what's in what block. You can't debug code if its not clear what's in what block, obviously.

Comment: @developerwjk thanks for downvoting i solved it on my own

Comment: You're welcome. When you get fired from your first programming job for producing spaghetti code, you'll think "I sure wish I had listened when that guy downvoted my question for complete and total lack of indenting."

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a mess and I couldn't be bothered to reindent it but point is switching to associative array instead of an object probably solves all of your problems:

Since I am not sure what you're trying to achieve exactly I just changed it to be one-to-one code of yours, just using `json_decode($var, true);` and then replace all references to the decoded json.

```
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>How to parse JSON file with PHP</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="header">
                <img src="images/BeWebDeveloper.png" />
            </div><!-- header -->
            <h1 class="main_title"><?php echo $title; ?></h1>
            <div class="content">
                <table>
                    <?php
                    $rt=$jfo['result']['n'];

                    for($i=0; $i < $rt; $i++) {
                        $x=1;
                        ?>
                        <th>
                            <?php
                            $ze=0;
                            $p=$r.$ze;
                            echo $jfo['result'][$p];

                            ?>
                        </th>
                        <?php foreach ($posts as $post) {
                $a = $i + 1;
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td>

                        <h2><?php echo $post[$a]; ?></h2>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <h2><?php

                            $z=$a.$x; echo $post[$z]; ?></h2>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php
                            echo $a.$x;
                            $x++;
                            ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php
            } // end foreach

            $r++;
} ?>
</table>
</div><!-- content -->
<div class="footer">
    Powered by <a href="http://www.bewebdeveloper.com">bewebdeveloper.com</a>
</div><!-- footer -->
</div><!-- container -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it on my own. What I wanted to achieve through my JSON parsing is, I wanted an dynamic file that would be useful for me while developing an ecommerce site where I need not add all specifications features etc. of an product into a database rather fetch complete details from an JSON file.

Just remove `$posts = $jfo->result->$r;` from the top and place it in the for loop.

```
 for($i=0; $i < $rt; $i++) {

 $posts = $jfo->result->$r;

   //rest codes
   }
```

Every time `$r` value gets incremented you must call the array corresponding to `$r` value but as it was not inside the loop, my code was trying to fetch values without incrementing to the new value and thus the error.